# Spliting an input value to different fields in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using Pyspark dataframe to process a log file. Below is my sample log which I have read from a file using spark.read.text

```
[Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /export/home/htdocs/test

[Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /export/home/htdocs/test
```

I want to split this log into 5 fields namely Timestamp,Info,URL,Message,Path.

How to split like that ?
Please help me in this issue. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got a couple of options.

## Delimiters

So your log file has got some obvious delimiters that you can split on. For this use the `split` function

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "split_column", 
    F.split(F.col("log_column"), delimiter)
)

# "split_column" is now an array, so we need to pull items out the array
df = df.withColumn(
    "timestamp",
    F.col("split_column").getItem(0)
)
```

As you have a couple of different fields, you'll need to combine multiple splits with a `trim`.

Something like,

```py
# Split on square brackets
df = df.withColumn(
    "split_bracket_column", 
    F.split(F.col("log_column"), "]")
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "timestamp",
    F.col("split_bracket_column").getItem(0).trim()
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "info",
    F.col("split_bracket_column").getItem(1).trim()
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "url",
    F.col("split_bracket_column").getItem(2).trim()
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "remaining",
    F.col("split_bracket_column").getItem(3).trim()
)

# Split the remaining on the colon ":"
df = df.withColumn(
    "split_colon_column", 
    F.split(F.col("remaining"), ":")
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "messsage",
    F.col("split_colon_column").getItem(0).trim()
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "path",
    F.col("split_colon_column").getItem(1).trim()
)

# Clean up temp columns
df.drop("split_bracket_column")
df.drop("remaining")
df.drop("split_colon_column")
```

## Regex

As the format is pretty fixed, you can do the same thing with a regex.

```py
import re

regex_pattern = r"\[()\]\[()\]\[()\]()\: ()"
match_groups = ["timestamp", "info", "URL", "message", "path"]

for i in range(re.compile(regex_pattern).groups):
    df = df.withColumn(
        match_groups[i], 
        F.regexp_extract(F.col(log_column), regex_pattern, i + 1),
    )
```

Where, `log_column` is the column in your Spark dataframe with the log messages.

NOTE: Check that `regex_pattern` as I don't have an editor in front of me.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! In the delimiter method what I can use as delimiter for the above log code ?   Also in regex method I'm getting column not defined error  in  'F.regexp_extract(F.col(column),regex_pattern,i+1)'  Should I replace column with match_groups[i] ?

Comment: For the delimiter code - you can use `]` for the delimiter on the first pass. I'd then use `:` on the second pass.

Comment: For the Regex, you need to replace `column` with whatever the log message is called in your Spark dataframe - sorry I assumed your data was already in a dataframe

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please change this in the code so that I accept your solution as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 val sUDF = udf((s: String) => {
    val s2 = s.split("]").map(_.replace("[", "").trim).reverse
    s2.tail.reverse ++ s2.head.split(": ")
  })

  val sDF = Seq("[Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /export/home/htdocs/test")
    .toDF("log")
    .withColumn("arr", sUDF('log))
    .select(
      'arr(0).alias("Timestamp"),
      'arr(1).alias("Info"),
      'arr(2).alias("URL"),
      'arr(3).alias("Message"),
      'arr(4).alias("Path")
    )

  sDF.show(false)
//  +------------------------+-----+----------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+
//  |Timestamp               |Info |URL             |Message                              |Path                    |
//  +------------------------+-----+----------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+
//  |Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000|error|client 127.0.0.1|client denied by server configuration|/export/home/htdocs/test|
//  +------------------------+-----+----------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can you write this code in Python if possible ?

Comment: Note that using UDFs in Python will be significantly slower than using built-ins - which you might care about if your logs are small, but if you're talking about MBs of files, it'll be pretty substantial.

Comment: Thanks Morgan I will look into that !